# JOptionPane Information Message

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
    public static String GetName()
    {
        String Name;
        String userName = "";
        int GN = 0;
        if(GN == 0)
        {
        userName =
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is you name?");
        GN = 1;
        }
        Name = userName;
        return Name;
    }
    public static void Welcome_P()
    {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        Icon welcomeIcon = new ImageIcon("Welcome.gif");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t \t▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇\n"
                + "\t \t▇▇Welcome " + GetName() + " to " + GetAuthorsName() + " Quirky Program▇▇\n"
                + "\t \t▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇\n", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, "Welcome", welcomeIcon);
    }
```

I keep getting this message and I'm new to programing I don't understand what I need to do to fix this. incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String. This happens when I put the JOptionPane.Information_Message

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the underlying constructor the wrong way. The title follows the message and not the message type. Try it this way:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null, 
    "message", 
    "title",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
    welcomeIcon);
```